# Nativescript - permission needed for saving file to DOWNLOAD folder (Android)

Tags: nativescript

android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS )

I'm saving a file to the download folder and also asking for
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Is that required?

Also - the system permission message is a more ominous permission
required for Photo folder or something similar and some users
have questioned why I need that.

I'm downloading an APK file just before installing it.

Comment: On some newer API levels, you might need to grant permission runtime. Meaning that only requiring permission via AndroidManifest file is not enough you will have to explicitly ask for them when the app starts (or when the user navigates to the page that needs them If that is the case use something like this https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Cosmos-Databank/blob/d1db9e4a33a14ba558a2471089eec879589f35dd/app/views/drawer-page.js#L14-L26

Comment: Thanks - I do do that. The problem is that the Android system permission dialog says - needs access to the PHOTO folder. Would be much better if it said DOWNLOAD folder or something similar.